# How to ensure only one tab is coloured upon clicking?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to write a function such that when you click a tab (created using bootstrap) it changes to a gold color. This bit works fine, however, I want to toggle the active property of each tab (bootstrap) so that it's on to give a nice white outline. The issue is unless you click on the same tab again, it stays white. Any ideas? Thanks.

This is my work so far:

```js
let timesClicked = 1;

let navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.changeColor');
navItems.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    timesClicked++;
    console.log(timesClicked);
    let previousItem = item;
    if (timesClicked % 2 == 0) {
      item.style.color = "#f0a500";
      item.classList.toggle('active');
      console.log(item);
    } else {
      previousItem.classList.toggle('active');
      console.log(previousItem);
    };

    navItems.forEach(otherItem => {
      if (otherItem !== item) {
        otherItem.style.color = "#1A1C20";
        /*
        item.addEventListener("click", () =>
          item.classList.toggle('active'));
       ;*/
      };
    });

  });
})
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill justify-content-center mt-3" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link changeColor active" id="mathematics-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Mathematics" role="tab"
      aria-controls="Mathematics" aria-selected="true">Mathematics</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link changeColor black-text-start" id="english-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab"
      aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">English</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link changeColor black-text-start" id="verbal-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab"
      aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Verbal</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link changeColor black-text-start" id="nonverbal-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab"
      aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Nonverbal</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are over complicating your `code` this can simply be done using `querySelectorAll` and `forEach` method.

Just remove the `active` class and `color` from all the `nav items` and then add only to the `clicked` menu item only using [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) method

**Simplified code Demo:**

```js
let navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.changeColor');
navItems.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    navItems.forEach(otherItem => {
      otherItem.style.color = "#1A1C20";
      otherItem.classList.remove('active');
    });
    e.target.classList.add('active');
    e.target.style.color = "#f0a500";
  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill justify-content-center mt-3" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link changeColor active" id="mathematics-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Mathematics" role="tab" aria-controls="Mathematics" aria-selected="true">Mathematics</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link changeColor black-text-start" id="english-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">English</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link changeColor black-text-start" id="verbal-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Verbal</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link changeColor black-text-start" id="nonverbal-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Nonverbal</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for this, but why would you do this:  e.target.classList.remove('active'); . Doesn't this just remove the active toggle every time the tab is clicked?

Comment: @github292929 no problem :) `e.target` will ensure we only add to clicked item. and sorry that a typo. it should be `e.target.classList.add('active'); ` add not remove.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense now, I was just wondering when does otherItem get specified? In my code otherItem are defined as those != item - just confused on this bit. Thanks and I will accept your answer.

Comment: @github292929 sure let me clarify. `Otheritem` comes from the `forEach` loop which is inside the `click` function. It only run when we click on a tab it removes all the colors and active classes for each `li` items and then `e.target` add the color and class to clicked item only.

Comment: sorry let me clarify I'm just wondering how does the forEach loop know that Otheritem is different to item? thanks

Comment: actually, @ - Always Helping, I think I know what you did now. You basically initially used navItems.forEach(other items =>...) to set the default color to black and remove the active status. Then, for just the target causing the click event, you change the active status and color. Got it!

Answer (score 4):

Based on your code, I did following steps to correct it:

1. set first tab as the default active one before clicking.
2. when click on any tab, deactive previous tab, and remember this active one by the variable `previousItem`(you should declare this variable outside forEach(..)).

```js
let navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.changeColor');
let previousItem = navItems[0];

navItems.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {

    if(previousItem == item)return;

    item.style.color = "#f0a500";
    item.classList.toggle('active');

    previousItem.classList.toggle('active');
    previousItem.style.color = "#1A1C20";

    previousItem = item;
 });
})
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill justify-content-center mt-3" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link changeColor active" id="mathematics-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Mathematics" role="tab"
      aria-controls="Mathematics" aria-selected="true" style="color:#f0a500;">Mathematics</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link changeColor black-text-start" id="english-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab"
      aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">English</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link changeColor black-text-start" id="verbal-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab"
      aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Verbal</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link changeColor black-text-start" id="nonverbal-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab"
      aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Nonverbal</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks! how did you add a return to if statement on one line? I.e. what's the logic?

Comment: this is way too much complicated and extra lines of code to achieve this simple menu toggle. See my answer. Also please add details to your answer for other readers.

Comment: @github292929 it's the short way to write the if statement  `if(previousItem == item){return;}` ,when you have only one line in the curly brace, you can spare the curly brace.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping thanks for your reminder, I just added details, also it's not too much complicated, you can see I kept the `console.logs and timesClicked`, so the OP can see the difference, your answer is great! but is that iterating all the tabs every time you click necessary?

Comment: @QiuZhou thank you. I do not think its unnecessary and there is no performance issue as well doing that - Since the goal is to write LESS code but achieve same results always.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Make sense, happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution to your problem

```
let navItem = document.querySelectorAll('.changeColor');
function someFunction({ target }) {
  navItem.forEach((element) => {
    element.style.color = '#1A1C20';
    element.classList.remove('active');
  });
  target.style.color = '#f0a500';
  target.classList.toggle('active');
}
navItem.forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener('click', (e) => someFunction(e));
});
```